# Can't get data from my generated web service

Tags: rest

I generated a restful web service with netbeans from oracle database, baut when i try to get data that's what i get!!
Any suggestion and thanks.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAGyx.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Comment: As a thought, it looks as if it is trying to authenticate the user before they get to your page, but you don't have an authentication page set up.

Comment: thank you for you effort but i literally followed this tutorial, it's working with him :( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mISEAPKwYa0&t=3s

Comment: It is highly unlikely that anybody will follow that tutorial and do all the work to understand your problem. That's a massive investment in their time and energy. And supposing it works for them: how would that help you? You need to post **your code** here - at least enough for people to understand what you've done so they can offer informed advice.

Comment: Also, [please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution guys :)
It seems the error came from tomcat server i switched it with glassfish and everything is fine.

Comment: Can you give any more detail?